# How to write on a friend's wall using facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Am working on an application that should be able to write unto the wall of a friend after the user authorizes it. Currently, i can write unto my wall successfully through the application using the facebook graph API. Am facing difficulty in writing to a friends wall using the app. I have not been able to figure out whether i need extra permissions to do so or if need to do something different. I would be grateful if anyone could help me with any lead.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get an extended permissions for your app: **publish_stream**.
For reference see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

publish_stream - Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends...

Good luck